# Creating a Dynamic Horizontal Menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to create a horizontal menu in WordPress that can be changed on the fly by non-technical users without editing the theme directly. i.e. The graphics department :). I'm a .net developer and the way I would do this in .net is to create a database with the attributes of the link, and make a user friendly back-end to display the contents with CRUD.

Is there an easier way of doing this in WordPress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're building a theme? Base your menu on the new default [WordPress › TwentyTen](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/twentyten) theme's menu; it has easily configurable drop down CSS menus. For IE support, see http://firelords.net/wp-plugins/ie6-support-2010/ie6-support-2010.zip

There are other plugins, too, that provide easy menu generation in the Admin section for themes in general: [CSS Dropdown search WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=css+dropdown&sort=)